# Invariant induction over horn-clauses with Z3py

Tags: logic, z3, z3py, logic-programming

I am currently using Z3py to to deduce some invariants which are encoded as a conjunction of horn-clauses whilst also providing a template for the invariant. I'm starting with a simple example first if you see the code snippet below.

```
x = 0;
while(x < 5){
  x += 1
}
assert(x == 5)
```

This translates into the horn clauses

x = 0 => Inv(x)

x < 5 /\ Inv(x) => Inv(x +1)

Not( x < 5) /\ Inv(x) => x = 5

The invariant here is x <= 5.

I have provided a template for the invariant of the form a*x + b <= c
so that all the solver has to do is guess a set of values for a,b and c that can reduce to x <= 5.

However when I encode it up I keep getting unsat. If try to assert Not (x==5) I get a=2 , b = 1/8 and c = 2 which makes little sense to me as a counterexample.

I provide my code below and would be grateful for any help on correcting my encoding.

```
x = Real('x')
x_2 = Real('x_2')
a = Real('a')
b = Real('b')
c = Real('c')
s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([x],And(
Implies(x == 0 , a*x + b <= c),
Implies(And(x_2 == x + 1, x < 5, a*x + b <= c), a*x_2 + b <= c),
Implies(And(a*x + b <= c, Not(x < 5)), x==5)
)))
if (s.check() == sat):
    print(s.model())
```

Edit: it gets stranger for me. If I remove the x_2 definition and just replace x_2 with (x + 1) in the second horn clause as well as delete the x_2 = x_2 + 1, I get unsat whether I write Not( x==5) or x==5 in the final horn clause.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I changed all Reals to Ints and deleted the x_2 definition as described in my edit.

Suddenly it works and I get the proper invariant of x <= 5.

Nonetheless I'm a bit confused about the results that I got when using Reals so would be grateful for any explanation someone can offer that describes to me the issue with Reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things preventing your original encoding from working:

1) It's not possible to satisfy `x_2 == x + 1` for all `x` for a single value of `x_2`.  Thus, if you're going to write `x_2 == x + 1`, both `x` and `x_2` need to be universally quantified.

2) Somewhat surprisingly, this problem is satisfiable in the integers but not in the reals.  You can see the problem with the clause `x < 5 /\ Inv(x) => Inv(x + 1)`.  If `x` is an integer, then this is satisfied by `x <= 5`.  However, if `x` is allowed to be any real value, then you could have `x == 4.5`, which satisfies both `x < 5` and `x <= 5`, but not `x + 1 <= 5`, so `Inv(x) = (x <= 5)` does not satisfy this problem in the reals.

Also, you might find it helpful to define `Inv(x)`, it cleans up the code quite a bit.  Here is the encoding of your problem with those changes:

```
from z3 import *

# Changing these from 'Int' to 'Real' changes the problem from sat to unsat.
x = Int('x')
x_2 = Int('x_2')
a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')
c = Int('c')

def Inv(x):
    return a*x + b <= c

s = Solver()

# I think this is the simplest encoding for your problem.
clause1 = Implies(x == 0 , Inv(x))
clause2 = Implies(And(x < 5, Inv(x)), Inv(x + 1))
clause3 = Implies(And(Inv(x), Not(x < 5)), x == 5)
s.add(ForAll([x], And(clause1, clause2, clause3)))

# Alternatively, if clause2 is specified with x_2, then x_2 needs to be
# universally quantified.  Note the ForAll([x, x_2]...
#clause2 = Implies(And(x_2 == x + 1, x < 5, Inv(x)), Inv(x_2))
#s.add(ForAll([x, x_2], And(clause1, clause2, clause3)))

# Print result all the time, to avoid confusing unknown with unsat.
result = s.check()
print result
if (result == sat):
    print(s.model())
```

One more thing: it's a bit strange to me to write `a*x + b <= c` as a template, because this is the same as `a*x <= d` for some integer `d`.

Comment: Many thanks! yes the template is a bit redundant. It is because I am working on a template generator that looks at possible combinations of base-components (such as '+' and '-' )which can introduces redundancy. This is something I will be optimising for later on.